# Wordpress post spam

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im having Spam post on a clients WordPress site, the post does not have author or categories, I dont know how this post are beeing made, only two admins in the site have rights to post. Any idea where to start looking for?

The site has Woocommerce and WooCommerce Role Based Price plugins only. Also a child theme of Storefront.

Comment: Are you using Akismet to block post and comment spam?

Comment: Im not using any other plugins,I prevent comment spam by review them before publishing, so i got no problem there, the thing that I dont understand is how a post can be made without user registration.

Comment: Akismet helps protect your site from comment spam but also unauthorised access. What access levels do new users get to your site? Check your admin/Settings/General for this.

Comment: Now I see, looks like I also have installed User role editor plugin and deleted it after creating a new User Role called "client", it only has access to read, maybe deleting the plugin has given access to "client" to post?

Comment: still the only one who has post on wordpress > users section is the owner of the site.

Comment: Check that user and update their access.

Comment: Hey @NathanielFlick, I did that but today I got another 10 post createad at the same time with no author, How is possible to have post without author?, also they fall in the default category which at least is good.

Comment: You need to lock down your comments with a captcha.

Comment: the spam is not on comments, they are posts. @NathanielFlick